# Why aren't the entries in a Kotlin Pair mutable?

Tags: kotlin

I have a MutableList of Pairs and I'd like to decrement the value of the first entry so my condition my pass(change):

```
while(n > 0) {
    if(sibice[i].first > 0) {
        sum += sibice[i].second
        //sibice[i].first-- will not compile
        n--
    } else i++
}
```

But the Pair class doesn't let me do that, besides creating my own pair is there any other workaround and why is this even the case?

Comment: Could you add the part where you instantiate sibice?

Comment: val sibice : MutableList<Pair<Int,Int>> = MutableList(m) { Pair(0,0) }

I resolved the issue by making my own Pair class, but that's beyond the point, anyway I made my own Pair (Par): class Par<T1, T2> constructor(var first : T1, var second : T2)

Comment: You could always define your own `data class MutablePair<T, U>(var first: T, var second: U)`

Comment: "besides creating my own pair is there any other " I solved the problem by doing that, but I wanted to check for alternatives

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Like with all entities, issues arise with mutability.

In your case you can just update the list-entry with a new pair of values.

```
val newPair = oldPair.copy(first = oldPair.first-1)
```

Or directly use an array of length 2 instead `intArrayOf(0, 0)`. So you can access the elements directly.

```
while(n > 0) {
    if(sibice[i][0] > 0) {
        sum += sibice[i][1]
        sibice[i][0]--
        n--
    } else i++
}
```

You could even define extension values `first` and `second` to the `IntArray` type and use it the same like before.

```
val IntArray.second get() = get(1)
var IntArray.first
    set(value) = set(0, value)
    get() = get(0)
```

Comment: It's the case because that is the tradition, and the expectation, and often the requirement in functional programming.