# How to change pair value in arguments in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I know Pair is immutable in Kotlin. The question is that arguments is also immutable in Kotlin. So when I got a code like this.

```
fun bind(pair: Pair<String, Boolean>) {
   // Change pair value here
}
```

pair = pair.copy() is not working here. I don't know how to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aren't the entries in a Kotlin Pair mutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002406/why-arent-the-entries-in-a-kotlin-pair-mutable)

Comment: The op is not trying to mutate `pair.first` or `pair.second`, they're trying to mutate 
 the `pair` parameter, which is also immutable. The possible duplicates refer to something different.

Comment: @series0ne What makes you think that they want o do that? I don't see OP mention "parameter". I do however see him mention "value"

Comment: @TimCastelijns `pair = pair.copy()`

Comment: @TimCastelijns "The question is that **arguments** is also immutable in Kotlin" - Okay, I said *parameter* and not *argument*.

Comment: @series0ne oh I misunderstood, I thought you were talking about the type parameters

Comment: @TimCastelijns Oh I see, yes that adds another layer of confusion into the mix! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Pair` is immutable, you can't just replace the pair value except you are using reflection. Either change `Pair` to something mutable or stick with it and return a new `Pair` instead either with `copy` (setting only some of the values) or with the following:

```
fun bind(pair: Pair<String, Boolean>) = pair.let { (left, right) -> // destructuring
  // exchange pair values here... just showing a sample:
  left.toInt() to right.toString() // this is basically the same as Pair(left.toInt(), right.toString())
} // in this example it returns a Pair<Int, String>
```

While you could probably introduce your own `MutablePair`-class I would rather stick to the immutability and adapt your code to handle it appropriately. Mutability can be a problem; even more so if someone else does not expect that your pair is mutable.

Answer (score 2):

You can not write to the `pair` value itself since it's [immutable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/immutability.html), instead create a copy of the value like so:

```
val pair2 = pair.copy()
```

And use `pair2` value instead of `pair` itself.

Also see [this helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47149372/5457878).

Comment: This was not the exact question and answer of the user. The user here wants to know how to use `copy()` explicitly while the answer I copied here answered how to **modify** a `Pair`.

Comment: You are right about the title and I understand your point of view. However OP gave an example of `pair = pair.copy() `, so I assume he wants to use `copy()`, but possibly does not understand that writing again to `pair` will not work out since it's immutable. My answer here tries to address that, hence I didn't mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `copy()` to create a changed copy. (Works for every [data-class.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html#copying))

```
fun bind(pair: Pair<String, Boolean>) {
   val pairCopy = pair.copy(first = "something else")
}
```

Then use `pairCopy` in the following code.